# Creating JSON string with consistent quotes

Tags: python, json

I am trying to dynamically create a string , in Python and print it, however I am ending up with mixed quotes formats in the string produced.  The output I want is `"{'name': 'test', 'scope': {'sites': [41, 42]}, 'version': '2.'}"` with consistent quotes.

This is the code I am using to try to dynamically construct the string

```
name = "test"
ID1 = "41"
ID2 = "42"

IDS = f'{{"ID": [{ID1}, {ID2}]}}'

report = {
    "name": f"{name}",
    "scope": f'"{IDS}"',
    "version": "2."
}

print(report)
```

I get the output "`{'name': 'test', 'scope': '"{"sites": [41, 42]}"', 'version': '2.'}"`

I have tried escaping the quotes and changing the order of the quotes eg `"scope": f"'{IDS}'",` but I have been unable to produce the desired string with consistent quotes.

How can I dynamically create the string I am trying to with consistent quotes without using string substitution after creation?

Comment: [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: That's not a JSON what you want. JSON has double-quotes, so it would be `{"name": "test", "scope": {"sites": [41, 42]}, "version": "2."}`.

Answer (score 3):

.JSON are just dictionary files, you could use Python dictionary to create what you want:

```py
name = "test"
ID1 = 41
ID2 = 42

IDS = {"ID": [ID1, ID2]}

report = {}
report["name"] = name
report["scope"] = IDS
report["version"] = 2.

print(report)
```

---

```bash
{'name': 'test', 'scope': {'ID': [41, 42]}, 'version': 2.0}
```

Notice that every type can be stored in a dictionary, so no need to use only string, for example here we have string, int, and list.

But as @tevemadar mentioned, dictionary and JSON are not exactly the same. It therefore possible in Python to convert one to the other:

```py
import json

# Convert Python to JSON  
json_report = json.dumps(report, indent = 4)
```